# Grids of basemap when exporting PDF in QGIS print layout

Tags: qgis, export, pdf, grids-graticules, basemap

I've been getting perpendicular lines through my basemap imagery in my QGIS layout exports to PDF (see photo).

Some notes:

- The lines do not appear on the export screen.
- I have guides built into the layout, but they are not aligned with the lines.
- They appear across different imagery sources both WMS and downloaded .TIFF and .JPEG raster files.
- They do not appear when I export the composer as an image.
- They are not unique to the print layout, when I create another layout from scratch they still show up.
- They do not appear in my colleagues' exports using the same .qgis template files.
- The lines do not go through the shapes which make up the frame surrounding the basemap.
- The lines are in the same spot every time, towards the bottom and right.

I haven't been able to find anyone else with this issue on line.

My QGIS version is 3.20.3 and I'm on Windows 10 Home, 10.0.19043 Build 19043

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the grid lines if you disable the tiled raster layer export in the PDF Export Options:

[image]

BTW: it would be cool if QGIS Server will support this feature one day (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/51238).

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I am on QGIS 3.24.3 and still experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In layout view go to 'Layout' tap > 'Export Settings' and check 'Always export as vectors'
Had same problem at that moment ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I am on QGIS 3.24.3 and still experiencing this issue.

Comment: Very strange. Maybe a complete reinstall with OSGeo4W could help in your case. Would recommend to delete the old installation completely.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

From print layout, go to Settings > Layout Options ...

[image]

Then change under Grid Appearance, change Grid Colour to transparent

[image]

On PDF Export Options, I have the following:

[image]

Now the grid lines have disappeared!